# Complex matlab-like data structure in python (numpy/scipy)

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have data currently structured as following in Matlab

```
item{i}.attribute1(2,j)
```

Where item is a cell from i = 1 .. n each containing the data structure of multiple attributes each a matrix of size 2,j where j = 1 .. m. The number of attributes is not fixed.

I have to translate this data structure to python, but I am new to numpy and python lists. What is the best way of structuring this data in python with numpy/scipy?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you need to work with the data?  The simplest thing would be to just dump everything in to a sequence of nested lists, but I have a sneaking suspicion that wouldn't support the type of functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've often seen the following conversion approaches:

matlab array -> python numpy array

matlab cell array -> python list

matlab structure  -> python dict

So in your case that would correspond to a python list containing dicts, which themselves contain numpy arrays as entries

`item[i]['attribute1'][2,j]`

**Note**

Don't forget the 0-indexing in python!

[Update]

**Additional: Use of classes**

Further to the simple conversion given above, you could also define a dummy class, e.g.

```
class structtype():
    pass
```

This allows the following type of usage:

```
>> s1 = structtype()
>> print s1.a
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-7734865fddd4> in <module>()
----> 1 print s1.a
AttributeError: structtype instance has no attribute 'a'
>> s1.a=10
>> print s1.a
10
```

Your example in this case becomes, e.g.

```
>> item = [ structtype() for i in range(10)]
>> item[9].a = numpy.array([1,2,3])
>> item[9].a[1]
2
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple version of the answer by @dbouz , using the idea by @jmetz

```
class structtype():
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.Set(**kwargs)
    def Set(self,**kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
    def SetAttr(self,lab,val):
        self.__dict__[lab] = val
```

then you can do

```
myst = structtype(a=1,b=2,c=3)
```

or

```
myst = structtype()
myst.Set(a=1,b=2,c=3)
```

and still do

```
myst.d = 4 # here, myst.a=1, myst.b=2, myst.c=3, myst.d=4
```

or even

```
myst = structtype(a=1,b=2,c=3)
lab = 'a'
myst.SetAttr(lab,10) # a=10,b=2,c=3 ... equivalent to myst.(lab)=10 in MATLAB
```

and you get exactly what you'd expect in matlab for `myst=struct('a',1,'b',2,'c',3)`.

The equivalent of a cell of structs would be a `list` of `structtype`

```
mystarr = [ structtype(a=1,b=2) for n in range(10) ]
```

which would give you

```
mystarr[0].a # == 1
mystarr[0].b # == 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a good example how to create a structured array in Python like it is done in MATLAB, you might want to have a look at the scipy homepage ([basics.rec](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html)).

### Example

```
x = np.zeros(1, dtype = [('Table', float64, (2, 2)),
                         ('Number', float),
                         ('String', '|S10')])

# Populate the array
x['Table']  = [1, 2]
x['Number'] = 23.5
x['String'] = 'Stringli'

# See what is written to the array
print(x)
```

The printed output is then:

```
[([[1.0, 2.0], [1.0, 2.0]], 23.5, 'Stringli')]
```

Unfortunately, I did not find out how you can define a structured array without knowing the size of the structured array. You can also define the array directly with its contents.

```
x = np.array(([[1, 2], [1, 2]], 23.5, 'Stringli'),
                dtype = [('Table', float64, (2, 2)),
                         ('Number', float),
                         ('String', '|S10')])

# Same result as above but less code (if you know the contents in advance)
print(x)
```

Comment: I can understand that you want to be faithful to the matlab format.. but isnt the functionality the same as a dict?

Comment: @zwep No, there are more functionalities on structured arrays. NumPy can also perform its optimized algorithms on such structured arrays. This is why I use it.

Comment: thanks for this. It seems that these structured arrays with multi indexing can behave the same way as a simple pandas dataframe. That is great! :)

Comment: Well, pandas relies on numpy. It just wraps the numpy array in a bit of overhead. For this reason I never started using pandas. I hope you understand the origin of this similarity now.

Answer (score 0):

For some applications a `dict` or list of dictionaries will suffice. However, if you really want to emulate a MATLAB `struct` in Python, you have to take advantage of its OOP and form your own struct-like class.

This is a simple example for instance that allows you to store an arbitrary amount of variables as attributes and can be also initialized as empty (Python 3.x only). `i` is the indexer that shows how many attributes are stored inside the object:

```
class Struct:
    def __init__(self, *args, prefix='arg'): # constructor
        self.prefix = prefix
        if len(args) == 0:
            self.i = 0
        else:
            i=0
            for arg in args:
                i+=1
                arg_str = prefix + str(i)
                # store arguments as attributes
                setattr(self, arg_str, arg) #self.arg1 = <value>
            self.i = i
    def add(self, arg):
        self.i += 1
        arg_str = self.prefix + str(self.i)
        setattr(self, arg_str, arg)
```

You can initialise it empty (i=0), or populate it with initial attributes. You can then add attributes at will. Trying the following:

```
b = Struct(5, -99.99, [1,5,15,20], 'sample', {'key1':5, 'key2':-100})
b.add(150.0001)
print(b.__dict__)
print(type(b.arg3))
print(b.arg3[0:2])
print(b.arg5['key1'])

c = Struct(prefix='foo')
print(c.i) # empty Struct
c.add(500) # add a value as foo1
print(c.__dict__)
```

will get you these results for object b:

```
{'prefix': 'arg', 'arg1': 5, 'arg2': -99.99, 'arg3': [1, 5, 15, 20], 'arg4': 'sample', 'arg5': {'key1': 5, 'key2': -100}, 'i': 6, 'arg6': 150.0001}
<class 'list'>
[1, 5]
5
```

and for object c:

```
0
{'prefix': 'foo', 'i': 1, 'foo1': 500}
```

Note that assigning attributes to objects is general - not only limited to `scipy`/`numpy` objects but applicable to all data types and custom objects (arrays, dataframes etc.). Of course that's a toy model - you can further develop it to make it able to be indexed, able to be pretty-printed, able to have elements removed, callable etc., based on your project needs. Just define the class at the beginning and then use it for storage-retrieval. That's the beauty of Python - it doesn't really have exactly what you seek especially if you come from MATLAB, but it can do so much more!