# Dynamically increase number of fields in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

With the help of "[Complex matlab-like data structure in python (numpy/scipy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637045/complex-matlab-like-data-structure-in-python-numpy-scipy)" I came up with:

```
s=(5,3)
a=np.zeros(s, dtype=[('Int1', int),
                     ('Int2', int),
                     ('Str1', '|S5')])

a[0,0]=(1,2,'abcde')
a[0,1]=((5,2,'fghij'),(7,9,'klmno'))
```

The problem is, that in some fields of my array `a`, just like in field `a[0,1]`, I want to add *one or more* extra "information" just like in my code  example.  I don't know how many extra information I have to write into which part of my matrix, but I will always have to write tuples with the `dtype=[(int, int, string)]`.

Of course, I get an error when I try to write into `a[0,1]` the way I do.

I would like to keep my matrix `a` 2-dimensional, but I would like to write several instances of my `dtype=[int, int, str]` into one field, similar to what I tried in field `a[0,1]`.

Hopefully, I could explain my problem in a comprehensible way.

Comment: Do you need to have these extras infos "nested" on the same row of the matrix ? Coulnd't you do something like `a[0,0]=(1,2,'abcde')`;
`a[0,1]=(5,2,'fghij')`;`a[0,2]=(7,9,'klmno')` and know which row are linked (using a *dict*, or maybe an 4th element in your tuple as an identifier ?). Alternatively you can probably complete with 0/null values, like this : `a[1]=[(5,2,'fghij'),(7,9,'klmno'), (0, 0, None)]`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the question and suggestion! -- I could also use an identifier or another variable to reference. in case I use another cross-reference, I wouldn't need a 2-dimensional matrix anymore. I will have to write the fields of a[x,y] into a excel sheet, which is why I would prefer a 2-dimensional solution.

Comment: *"I will have to write the fields of a[x,y] into a excel sheet, which is why I would prefer a 2-dimensional solution"* - could you explain what you mean by this? I don't see how a 2D array would help in this case. Your data is still fundamentally "3D" in the sense that each individual "element" in the 2D array contains multiple values. Since a single cell can't contain two integers and a string, there's still no obvious way to represent `a` in a single 2D spreadsheet.

Comment: hi ali_m,
I agree with you, there is not obvious way to represent a in a single 2D spreadsheet, since it has some 3D characteristics...  But I have to fit it in a Excel sheet in this non-intuitive way: All the entries of for example a[0,1] will be in one excel field, and in this excel sheet I write them into a new line inside the same field... Thats how they want it!

Comment: Have you looked at `pandas.DataFrame`?  I think it is more suited to this sort of structure, especially if you want to convert it to an excel spreadsheet

Comment: @TheBlackCat, I haven't looked at it yet, but I will. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

A numpy array is probably the wrong data structure for this kind of flexibility.  Once created your array `a` takes up a fixed amount of memory.  It has 15 (5*3) records, and each record contains the 2 ints and one string with 5 characters. You can modify values, but you can't add new records, or change one record into a composite of two records.

Lists give you the flexibility to add elements and to change their nature.  A list contains pointers to objects located else where in memory.

An array of dtype=object behaves much like a list.  Its data buffer is the same sort of pointers.  `a=np.zeros((3,5), dtype=object)` is a 2d array, where each element can be a tuple, list, number, None, tuple of tuples, etc.  But with that kind of array you loose a lot of the 2d numeric calculation abilities.

With your structured array, the only way to increase its size or add fields is to make a new array and copy data over.  There are functions that assist in adding fields, but they do, in one way or other, what I just described.

---

With your definition, there are 3 fields, `['Int1','Int2','Str1']`

```
a=np.zeros(s, dtype=[('Int1', int),
                     ('Int2', int),
                     ('Str1', '|S5')])
```

Increasing the number of fields (by that concept of fields) would be something like

```
a1=np.zeros(s, dtype=[('Int1', int),
                     ('Int2', int),
                     ('Str1', '|S5'),
                     ('Str2', '|S5')])
```

That is adding a field named 'Str2'.  You could fill it with

for name in a.dtype.fields:
       a1[name] = a[name]

Now all records in a `a2` have the same data as in `a`, but they also have a blank `Str2` field.  You could set that field for each element individually, or as group with:

```
a['Str2'] = ...
```

But your attempt to change `A[0,1]` into a tuple of tuples is quite different.  It's like trying to replace an element of a regular numeric array with two numbers:

```
x = np.arange(10)
x[3] = [3,5]
```

That works for lists, `x=range(10)`, but not for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

My code would look like this now:

```
s=(5,3)   
a=np.zeros(s, dtype=object)  
a[0,0]=(1,2,'abcde')  
a[0,1]=((5,2,'fghij'),(7,9,'klmno'))
```

I can see/access the entries with:

```
print(a[0,1])
print(a[0,1][0])
print(a[0,1][1])
```