# Call Matlab Function with .mat file content as argument from Python

Tags: python, matlab, data-structures, scipy

I am building a software and a part of this software needs to read a .mat file and give the content to a matlab function as argument. The problem is that I have bad data structure I guess.

In fact my Matlab structure called `handles` doesn't have the same data structure than my `handles` in my Python ([after conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637045/complex-matlab-like-data-structure-in-python-numpy-scipy))

When I load the .mat file from python with `scipy.io.loadmat()`, I have those 4 keys:

[image]

So in `handles.simulation` there supposed to be this content:

[image]

[image]

So I use `matlab.engine` to call matlab function in my case the function is called `VS_Parametrise` and when I pass my `handles` which is a [dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637045/complex-matlab-like-data-structure-in-python-numpy-scipy):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import os
import Tkinter
import numpy as np

from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
from structDataConfFile import structConfFile

try:
    import matlab.engine
except:
    print "No matlabEngine installed"
    print "Running installation procedure..."
    print " "
    import installMatlabEngine
    print " "
    print "Application will exit now..."
    print "Please re-run this program to continue installation!"
    print " "
    exit()

# Environment PATH
Mlab = os.environ.get("MATLAB")
vssFolderPath=os.environ.get("CONTIAME")+'/4_Tools/Veh_Sim_Suite/VSimu'
ContimodelPath=os.environ.get("CONTIAME")

FILETYPES = [ ("text files", "*.mat") ]

handles = dict()

def selectConfFile():
    """ Return the path of .mat file

    Function that open files browser to choose a .mat file and build handles
    dictionary.
    """
    Tkinter.Tk().withdraw() # Close the root window
    in_path = askopenfilename(filetypes=FILETYPES)
    if len(in_path) == 0:
        handles['Simulation'] = list()
    elif len(in_path) > 0:
        handles['Simulation'] = structConfFile(in_path) # HERE I FILL SIMULATION
    handles['contimodel_path'] = ContimodelPath
    return in_path

def Parametrize(confFile):
    """ Return

    Argument:
    confFile    --  str()   Configuration File path

    Function that call MatLab function passing handles structure/dict as
    argument. The return value of MatLab function called VS_Parametrize(handles)
    is the modified handles structure.
    """
    eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
    eng.addpath(vssFolderPath)
    eng.VS_Parametrise(handles) ############# HERE I CALL VS_PARAMETRIZE
```

In my matlab function `handles.simulation` there are structure of structure of structure.

In Python it should be dictionary of dictionary of dictionary but I get this error:

[image]

And I don't understand why when i load the file in Python the first floor of the data structure is a dict and the second is a numpy.ndarray (1st floor: simulation, 2nd floor: parameter/info). Here is more documentation about [Matlab to Python variable](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/pass-data-to-matlab-from-python.html)

Any idea ?

Comment: `scipy.io.loadmat` loads MATLAB matrices as `numpy` arrays (`ndarray`), `cells` and `structs` as some combination of `numpy` object dtype arrays.  MATLAB functions, classes and special types don't have Python/numpy equivalents and don't load (well).  In other words, it's a means of transferring largely numeric data.

Comment: @hpaulj Ok so i guess in my case, it will be difficult to me to manage my **handles** variable between Python and Matlab :/